# React app yields TypeError when using productive build with xmlbuilder2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, yarnpkg

I have built a React app using https://create-react-app.dev/. Everything works fine when I start the app with `yarn start` in the development mode. But when I build the app using `yarn build` I get this error when triggering an XML conversion:

```
classCallCheck.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at e.exports (classCallCheck.js:3)
    at new n (NodeImpl.ts:93)
    at n.<anonymous> (createSuper.js:14)
    at new n (DocumentImpl.ts:69)
    at Object.t.create_document (CreateAlgorithm.ts:61)
    at new n (WindowImpl.ts:28)
    at Function.value (WindowImpl.ts:41)
    at Object.t.create_window (CreateAlgorithm.ts:47)
    at e.get (DOMImpl.ts:68)
    at new e (DOMImplementationImpl.ts:27)
```

I have tracked down the one line which throws this error:

```
import { create } from 'xmlbuilder2';
const xmlDoc = create({ version: '1.0', encoding: 'UTF-8', standalone: true }, jsObject);
```

So the conversion of my object into an XML triggers this error. In the dev environment the xmlbuilder2 works like a charm.

I am using `xmlbuilder2@2.1.3`

Has anybody an idea on how to approach this issue?

Here is the simple code to reproduce it:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { create } from 'xmlbuilder2';

const testJson = 
{
  "widget": {
    "debug": "on",
      "window": {
      "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
        "name": "main_window",
          "width": 500,
            "height": 500
    },
    "image": {
      "src": "Images/Sun.png",
        "name": "sun1",
          "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
              "alignment": "center"
    },
    "text": {
      "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
          "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
              "hOffset": 250,
                "vOffset": 100,
                  "alignment": "center",
                    "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
  }
}    

const xmlDoc = create(testJson);
const compl = xmlDoc.end({prettyPrint: true});
console.log(compl);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
node --version
v12.18.0

npm --version
6.14.5
```

I have the same on MacOS 10.14.6 as on Windows 10.

As a work around I use `xmlbuilder` instead.

Comment: Maybe someone could just reproduce and confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

After contacting the developer via github https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder2/issues/23 and creating an issue, it turned out to be a bug. Was fixed very quickly and does not occur any more in `xmlbuilder2@2.1.4`.